# Multiple Inheritance need to acces to private variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I don't know how access to private variable Multiple Inheritance.

In this code I create `person` class

```
class person {
    char name[20]; char lname[20];
public:
    person() {}
    person(char*n, char*ln);
    virtual void print(ostream&o);
};
person::person(char*n, char*ln)
{
    strcpy_s(name, 20, n);
    strcpy_s(lname, 20, ln);
}

void person::print(ostream&o)
{
    o << "name: " << name << "  " << "last name: " << lname << endl;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream&o, person&p)
{
    p.print(o);
    return o;
}
```

by Inheritance I create `student` and `teacher` class

```
class student : public virtual person
{friend class ststudent;

    long str;
public:

    student(char*n, char*ln, long s);
    void print(ostream&o);
};

student::student(char*n, char*ln, long s) :person(n, ln), str(s) {}

void student::print(ostream&o)
{
    person::print(o);
    o << "st_num :  " << str << endl;
}




class teacher : public virtual person
{
    long salary;

public:

    teacher(char*n, char*ln, long s);
    virtual void print(ostream&o);
};

teacher::teacher(char*n, char*ln, long sal) :person(n, ln), salary(sal) {}

void teacher::print(ostream&o)
{
    person::print(o);
    o << "salary :  " << salary << endl;
}
```

and in last class I use from Multiple Inheritance to create teacher assistant class but I don't know how to print the `str` and `salary`

```
class stteacher :public teacher, public student
{

public:
    stteacher(char*n, char*ln, long st, long sa)
        :student(0, 0, st), teacher(0, 0, sa), person(n, ln) {}
    virtual void print(ostream&o);
};

void stteacher::print(ostream& o)
{
    person::print(o);
    o << str << salary;

}
```

I don't know how to do it. I can create two variables in `stteacher` class or change `str` and `salary` from private to public variable but I think  I should do this with Multiple Inheritance.
Help me please.

Comment: You could change those variables from `private` to `protected`. What does this have to do with multiple inheritance?

Comment: Avoid multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Ron : Why?  It comes with some issues, but if you have an appropriate problem it can vastly simplify things.

Comment: Although it is *usually* a good idea to define member functions out of line, it is often worth defining them inline for an SO example - it usefully shrinks the amount of code.

Comment: OT: use std:string, not char arrays.

Comment: @Ron Saying “avoid multiple inheritance”, or “don’t use macros”, or any other instance of “don’t do what you are trying to do” is *completely unhelpful* if you don’t give some alternative. And in cases like those, where it’s a blanket “don’t use this feature of the language”, it’s especially useful to say *why not* and *what to do instead*.

Comment: @DanielH Let me quote Scott Meyers on this one: "Use multiple inheritance judiciously." Excerpt taken from the "Effective C++", chapter 6, item 40, page 192.

Comment: @Ron I’m not saying it’s bad advice; I’m saying it isn’t useful unless you say more. Quoting one sentence from an authority doesn’t change that. If that was all Scott Meyers had said on the subject, it would be equally useless; the reason he’s a useful authority is because he did say more than just that.

Answer (score 1):

Private data in a class cannot be accessed by any non-member, non-friend code.  Period.  Whether you use inheritance (or not) is irrelevant.

Thus, the only way for a different class to access that data is to:

- Provide accessor function(s) so that callers can fetch the data.  (If public, anyone can call it, but if it's a protected function then only derived classes gain access to it.)
- Alternately, make the class(es) that need access a friend of the class.  Friendship is something c++ programmers generally discourage, however, so only do so as a true last resort.
- Change the access to the data to be public.  (Very discouraged, as this defeats encapsulation entirely.)

Answer (score 0):

A pattern for accessing private variables is to make a public function that returns that variable:

```
class teacher : public virtual person
{
    long salary;

public:

    teacher(char*n, char*ln, long s);
    virtual void print(ostream&o);
    long get_salary(void){return salary;}
};
```

Then the implentation for stteacher::print would be:

```
void stteacher::print(ostream& o)
{
    person::print(o);
    o << get_salary();

}
```

or something like this.

Comment: ... or, if you only want the function available to derived classes (but not to everyone, you can make the function protected.

Answer (score 0):

Classes by default are private, which means that anything before specifying access modifiers is private.

Private methods / local variables can only be accessed by the class that defined them and it's friend classes. In your case, to define a friend class you should first tell to student and teacher what stteacher is.

C++ reads your code from top to bottom, so if you want to use a variable/class/macro/whatever, you should declare it above it's use.

In code, this would look something like:

```
extern class stteacher; //You tell C++ that 'stteacher' is a class

class person {};

class student : public virtual person {
    long str;
    friend class stteacher; //You make stteacher a friend of student
public:
    student(long str) : str(str) {}
};

class teacher : public virtual person {
    long salary;
    friend class stteacher; //You make stteacher a friend of teacher
public:
    teacher(long salary) : salary(salary) {}
};

class stteacher : public student, public teacher {
public:
    stteacher(long str, long salary) : student(str), teacher(salary) {}
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Salary: " << salary << "\nStr: " << str << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    long str = 10, salary = 100;
    stteacher(str, salary).print();
    return 0;
}
```

> Salary: 100
>
> Str: 10

Eventhough this works, I suggest it would be best to use a more apropiate access modifier, such as protected.

protected stuff can be accessed by the class which defines it, it's friend classes AND classes which inherits it.

Using protected access modifiers, the above code would look like:
    extern class stteacher; //You tell C++ that 'stteacher' is a class

```
class person {};

class student : public virtual person {
protected: //Can be accessed by it's childs
    long str;
public:
    student(long str) : str(str) {}
};

class teacher : public virtual person {
protected: //Can be accessed by it's childs
    long salary;
public:
    teacher(long salary) : salary(salary) {}
};

class stteacher : public student, public teacher {
public:
    stteacher(long str, long salary) : student(str), teacher(salary) {}
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Salary: " << salary << "\nStr: " << str << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    long str = 10, salary = 100;
    stteacher(str, salary).print();
    return 0;
}
```

> Salary: 100
>
> Str: 10